# Wildcard Services restart

Tags: windows, services, batch-file

Currently, we have setup a `.bat` file which lists all services to start / stop them eg.

```
SC start SERVICE1
SC start SERVICE2

SC stop SERVICE1
SC stop SERVICE2
```

We add new services all the time and the list grows and is difficult to maintain in the batch file.

Is it possible to use a WILDCARD like 'SC start SERVICE*' or something?

Comment: What windows version?

Answer (score 21):

Easy, via Powershell:

```
Get-service SERVICE* | stop-service -force

Get-service SERVICE* | start-service
```

Comment: I upvoted this one because it runs WAY faster than wmic. On my machine it takes about 2 milliseconds to get a list of services this way. It takes about 13000 milliseconds using wmic.

Comment: how do i combine these two commands in single go?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan What do you mean by that? Restarting multiple services? I mean they are already combined here.

Comment: Nevermind. I was hoping to not use the pipe also this solution was using two commands (one for stop and another for start). I found that the `Restart-Service` does them both "in single go". Checkout my answer.

Comment: Not sure if I should start a new topic for that, but how do I filter out the services that are disabled before actually trying to start them https://superuser.com/q/1742116/1018595 ?

Answer (score 20):

You can use `wmic` and SQL-ish wildcard syntax.

From a `cmd` console:

```
wmic service where "name like 'SERVICE%'" call startservice
```

From a `.bat` script:

```
wmic service where "name like 'SERVICE%%'" call startservice
```

Available verbs include `startservice`, `stopservice`, `pauseservice`, `resumeservice`, and others.  Do `wmic service call /?` for more info.

Comment: The query language is called WQL, BTW. It's a subset of SQL.

Comment: @Bob - Oh.  Ya learn something new every day.  `:>`

Comment: Just wanted to add one more thing. I ran into an error where the service name was not recognized. Turns out a service has a Service Name and a Display Name. The Service Name should be used, not the Display Name. You can find the Service Name with `sc query`

Answer (score 2):

**if you want a One Line command,**

You can use [Restart-Service Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176942.aspx) which is pre built in powershell.

To use Restart-Service simply call the cmdlet followed by the service name:

```
Restart-Service mysql57
```

To restart multiple services just specify the name of each service, separated by commas:

```
Restart-Service mysql57,apache
```

If you prefer, add the -displayname parameter and specify the service display name (the name shown in the Services snap-in) instead:

```
Restart-Service -displayname "Mysql 5.7 server"
```

This Cmdlet accepts wildcard matching as well. To restart all services starting with "mysql":

```
Restart-Service mysql*
```