# Powershell Get-Service : how do I filter out the services that are disabled?

Tags: powershell, services

I'm trying to start multiple services using :

```
Get-Service SERVICE* | Start-Service
```

When Get-Service returns services that are disabled, I run into the following error :

```
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

How do I filter out the services that are disabled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code. This will stop all started services, and then start all services, even if they hadn't been started before, but are not disabled either:

```
get-service SERVICE* | where-object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} `
                     | stop-service

get-service SERVICE* | where-object {$_.StartType -ne "Disabled" `
                            -and     $_.Status -eq "Stopped"} `
                     | start-service
```

You can simplify this if all services are supposed to be started if not disabled by using this code:

```
get-service SERVICE* | restart-service
```

Comment: I suppose I can apply the same principle to the stop operation by doing something like : `get-service SERVICE* | where-object {$_.StartType -ne "Disabled" -and $_.Status -eq "Running"} `
                     | stop-service`

Comment: Yes, definitely. :) Although in that case, you do not have to filter out disabled services, as a disabled service can't be started, so it won't be running anyway.

Comment: You can of course also use restart-service ;)